# Android ImageView: Replace Image (Drawable) While keeping View Size

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, android-drawable

**In Short**
I have an `ImageView` with size set to `wrap_content`.
The image has a `drawable` already set, and everything looks great.
Now, I want to change the `drawable`, while forcing the `ImageView` to keep it's size.

**Explanation**
Well, the easy answer is of course to set the width & height to a fixed size.
But in my case, I am copying an `ImageView` + layout from a `Google Map` to add my custom map button. It works well, because I have an icon with same size.
Now I want to change the icon for a moment (loading icon btw), but because the `Drawable` source is larger, it changes the `ImageView` size accordingly.
`ScaleType` doesn't work as the width and height are not fixed.

**What I've Tried**
1. Setting the new `Drawable` bounds using `getBounds` on the old one.
2. `setRight()` on the `ImageView` with the right bound of the existing map button (the original one which doesn't change).
(left is already fixed, it's inside a `RelativeLayout`).

**Some (working) Code** of how I created the new button

```
        ImageView newBtn = new ImageView(context);
        newBtn.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
        newBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.map_btn_background);
        newBtn.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        newBtn.setImageResource(imageResId);
        newBtn.setClickable(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationBtn.getLayoutParams();

        rlp = copyRelativeLayoutParams(rlp);

        //add to Google's map button layout
        btnContainer.addView(newBtn, rlp);
```

**Some (not working) Code** of how I change the drawable.
This is the point were I want the `ImageView` to keep it's size.

```
perfectlyMadeNewMapButtonImageView.setImageDrawable(mLoadingDrawable);
//mLoadingDrawable.setBounds(
//  perfectlyMadeNewMapButtonImageView.getDrawable().getBounds());
//  not working
```